# Change Navigation drawer item color filter also change the imageView which is use same image id

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

In the app have Navigation drawer contains a lot of menu items. The limitation is, there is one item will show its color instance of tint color but the other show tint. With this limitation, I decided to use the color filter to handle the icon color stage of the item drawer. This path work perfectly fine.

And my menu looks like this.

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_main"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_logo_24dp"
        android:title="@string/app_name" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_menu_settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_contact_us"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_markunread_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_menu_contact_us" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_faq"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_faq_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_menu_faq" />
```

**Every menu** expect the main menu should show color state like this

*selected: blue*

*not selected: gray*

**Main menu**

*selected: show its color*

*not selected: gray*

And the code to handle the state look like this

```
fun setSelectedMenuItemColor(selectedId: Int) {
  val menu = binding?.navView?.menu
   repeat(menu!!.size()) { i ->
     menu.getItem(i)?.icon?.colorFilter = when {
       menu.getItem(i).itemId == selectedId && selectedId == R.id.menu_main -> null
       menu.getItem(i).itemId == selectedId -> selectedFilterColor
       else -> idleFilterColor!!
     }
  }
}
```

**The problem is**

If I use imageView and set drawable as same as one of the menu item. The color state will change following the menu item. I don't want to change the tint color of the imageView. But it changes according to the menu item. Then I add tint color in imageView to change to different thin color but it still shows the same color of the menu. For example.

```
<ImageView
   android:tint="@color/black"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />
```

**In this case, imageView should show only black color. But it show gray or blue according to the menu.**

The expecting result is the imageView should tint color from the color I set in the XML

But the result is it shown the same tint color like the menu item.

I think it independently, can someone explains why this issue happened and how to fix it
**In the project use data binding and Kotlin**

Comment: use `app:srcCompat` instead of  `android:src`

Comment: Still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank everyone for helping me. I finally find the answer.

First of all `menu.getItem(i)?.icon?` is return drawable. And when using fixed something within this drawable, the drawable being cache despite that when I try to use the same image ID, it returns me the cache drawable. In order to fix it just call method `drawable.mutate()` for preventing the drawable cache. The final code should look like this.

```
fun setSelectedMenuItemColor(selectedId: Int) {
  val menu = binding?.navView?.menu
   repeat(menu!!.size()) { i ->
     menu.getItem(i)?.icon?.mutate()
     menu.getItem(i)?.icon?.colorFilter = when {
       menu.getItem(i).itemId == selectedId && selectedId == R.id.menu_main -> null
       menu.getItem(i).itemId == selectedId -> selectedFilterColor
       else -> idleFilterColor!!
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i can understand from your question is that you need to change the color of the selected item to blue and non selected items to grey for both the menu item and the imageView. You can use the colorstatelist to do this rather than writting the own logic to change the tint.

Follow this link to get the idea .. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Overall the solution could be like..

1. create a color state list xml file "selection_state.xml"

   `<selector>
     <item android:color='@color/your_preffered_color' 
     android:state_selected='true'/>
     <item android:color='@color/your_preffered_color'
     android:state_selected='false'/>
    </selector>`
2. Apply this a background to the view that you need to show on screen.

   `<ImageView android:background='@drawable/selection_state
    ...../>`

After this once if the view comes to the selected state automatically the color will be changed for all the view to which this state list is applied.

Comment: I don't want to change the tint color of the imageView. But it changes according to the menu item. Then I add tint color in imageView to change to different thin color but it still show the same color of the menu

Comment: I think since you apply the tint color this is getting applied to all the child in it. Tint is applied to the parent right. Try making the tint color null or the transparent @android:color/transparent for the imageView.

Comment: If I apply tint color to `R.id.menu_setting` now every place that use drawable `@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp` it always changes tint following the menu. But I don't want to.